# Actual time of a credit card transaction

Tags: credit-card, transaction

how can I find out the exact time my credit card was processed at a supermarket? My bank statement only tells me the day not the time

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: Have you tried calling your bank and asking?  Also note that while offline card processing has become very rare, it isn't totally gone yet.

Comment: I was surprised at the level of transaction detail in an American Express statement when my employer started a program with Amex cards for travel expenses.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the receipt from the supermarket.  Assuming you kept it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few ways I would do it:

1. Call the card provider and ask for that information.
2. (Going forward) Setup text or other (email, facebook) alerting for every transaction that crosses a threshold. That way you could narrow down the transaction to within 5 min of the actual swipe.

Comment: I have that set up, and I get the email one or two seconds after I pay. I actually have a script that reads the email and adds the line with all details to my accounting.

Comment: That is useful. While everyone may not be able to write programs to do this, there are definitely apps and free tools that may help with this.

Comment: it is especially useful if you're in a foreign country in some fishy restaurants - you know the _exact_ amount they charged you while the guy is still standing at your table...

Comment: You still have to be careful with the current exchange rates but yes, one can reasonably narrow down the bulk of the amount and the time.